# The difference in the use of images in MDX file (Gatsby)/

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I'm developing the Gatsby static site, so I want to use MDX for creating pages about completed projects. Is there a difference between using standard syntax for MDX in Gatsby:

```
![alt](path/to/image)
```

and using ordinary  tags:

```
<img src="path/to/image" alt="alt" />
```

Does "gatsby-remark-images" process images imported with a regular img tag or it understand only method from docs?

I ask because I need to style images, and when I code like example below I got big nesting construction.

```
<figure>

![alt](path/to/image)

</figure>
```

Code with regular img tag more simple, it doesn't contain p, span etc.

```
<figure>
  <img src="../images/test-work-img3.jpg" alt="alt text for small image" />
  <figcaption>Caption text for small image</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since you are specifically asking about behavior of an official plugin you might want to ask the people who built the plugin directly on the official Gatsby GitHub repo (https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby)

Comment: Thanks for advice! I'll do this.